# Which feature, algorithm is good for Speaker Verification

Tags: audio, similarity, verification, speech, speaker

I have a task with **speaker verification**.

My task is **calculate the similarity between two audio speech voice**, then compare with a threshold. 
Ex: similarity score between two audio is 70%, threshold is 50%. Hence the speaker is the same person.

The speech is **text-independent**, it's can be any conversation.

I have experiment in using MFCC, GMM for speaker recognition task, but this task is difference, just compare two audio feature to have the similarity score. I don't know which feature is good for speaker verification and which algorithm can help me to calculate similarity score between 2 patterns.

Hope to have you guys's advices,

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State of the art these days is xvectors:

[Deep Neural Network Embeddings for Text-Independent Speaker Verification](http://www.danielpovey.com/files/2017_interspeech_embeddings.pdf)

Implementation in Kaldi is [here](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/tree/master/egs/sre16/v2).

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on TIMIT Dataset for speaker verification. I have extracted mfcc features and trained a UBM for same, and adapted for each speaker.When it comes to adaptation I have used diagonal matrix.
How are you testing the wav files? However, when it comes to features you can use pitch and energy.